# SMS after install application

Tags: android, sms

I created an application and immediately after install I need to send a text message to a central server configuration.

How I can do that?

In applications such as WhatApps, just after installing you receive an SMS configuration. Anyone know how to do that.

Comment: There's no real way to detect an initial install of your own app, but if your app has a broadcast receiver to detect screen orientation change, or the screen being locked or something else that happens very frequently, you could try that.

Answer (score 2):

check for a boolean flag in shared preferences .

do stuff if not exist and insert this flag to sharedPrefeences .

sharedPreferences get deleted if user clears the data of app so better approach i will say is

you  manage device_id on server and do the same thing .

Answer (score 1):

You can use Service to run in the background and send the sms. However you cannot start a service directly after installing. The user has to interact with the application first.

See accepted answer and comments from [How to start android service on installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127044/how-to-start-android-service-on-installation) .

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the only possible way is that if there is a broadcast, that you can get after installation of any application. You receive that broadcast and send SMS from a service. But if there is no broadcast then I think you cant directly detect whether an application is just installed or not, or no trigger.