# Start service on installation of app without any activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to directly start a service without any activity. by making a service a launcher. I want to start service repeatedly at the interval of 2 min. can I use alarm. 
       At present I have an activity that starts an alarm using this
              manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), duration, loggerIntent);
 that starts service at every 2 min. How can I remove this activity.

Comment: You cannot do it after versions 2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to start a service on just installing the app, without user opening it first time. If you read the answers on the above two questions, you will get the gist.
1) [How to start a Service when .apk is Installed for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time)

2)  [How to start android service on installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127044/how-to-start-android-service-on-installation?lq=1)

Hope it helps you.