# Android: Detecting a Bluetooth device in a background service (Wearable)

Tags: android, wear-os, android-bluetooth

I want to create a service for my wearable that runs in background that will detect a Bluetooth device. I have written code that is able to detect the Bluetooth device but it uses Activity - onCreate() method to start scanning.

I read many articles on the internet about writing services that runs in background but in every example the service is started from the Activity. I want my service to be running without starting from any Activity. Is this possible? I mean when I install my app is it possible for the service to start running automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no way of starting a service without starting the Activity. I got the answer from there [How to start android service on installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127044/how-to-start-android-service-on-installation)